# Conceptual question about NSAutoreleasePools

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, memory-management

In my Cocoa program, wouldn't a really simple way of dealing with autoreleased objects be to just create a timer object inside the app delegate that calls the following method e.g. every 10 seconds:

```
if (pool) {
    // Release & drain the current pool to free the memory.
    [pool release];
}

// Create a new pool.
pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```

The only problems I can imagine are:

1) If the above code runs in a separate thread, an object might get autoreleased between the release call to the old pool and the creation of the new pool - that seems highly unlikely though.

2) It's obviously not that efficient, because the pool might get released if there's nothing in it. Likewise, in the 10 second gap, many many objects might be autoreleased, causing the pool to grow a lot.

Still, the above solution seems pretty suitable to small and simple projects. Why doesn't anybody use it? What's the best practice of using NSAutoreleasePools?

Comment: What do you mean 'deal' with autoreleased objects? Do you have a problem with them?

Comment: You're trying to outthink the frameworks based on incorrect assumptions. Your app already has an autorelease pool, and it's already drained for you at the end of the runloop. Here's official documentation on autorelease pools: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-CJBFBEDI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use an autorelease pool *at all*, unless you're explicitly creating threads on your own.  The framework should handle all this stuff for you pretty well; maybe you're misunderstanding what happens to an object when you send it an `autorelease` message?

Comment: I thought you had to `release` an NSAutoreleasePool to free up the memory used by the autoreleased objects. Am I wrong?

Comment: @ryyst, yes you are wrong.  The autorelease pool gets cleared out at the end of each event loop.  The only time you need to do it on your own is in some special threading circumstances.

Comment: OK, thanks! So in the end, it actually works kind of like I posted above (regularly freeing the memory).

Comment: @ryyst: Yes, it does, but just for trivia, instead of using a timer, you would probably want to use a runloop observer and clear it at a specific point through each iteration of the loop. Again, though, you would only do this if you are creating and managing your own threads.

Comment: ryyst: You need to release an autorelease pool when you create an autorelease pool; specifically, you need to release the pool you create. You usually don't need to create a pool in a normal Cocoa application.

Answer (score 0):

An NSAutoreleasePool is always thread local.

The pool will be automatically flushed every tick of the run loop. Between the 10 seconds when your NSTimer fires, there are already over hundreds of ticks passed, so the pool has been cleared over hundreds times.